# Sending events from Node.js to frontend javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't find very good info on this. I might be asking the wrong question because it seems like a common task!! Any info? Specifically, I would like to have a progressbar for formidable uploads.

I have basic  formidable usage:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('received upload:\n\n');
  res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
});
```

And I want to add a progress bar to the page when it's loading. I think I have to use this event:

```
form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
});
```

But I'm not sure how to send that event to my front event js that's controlling how the progress bar moves on the page.

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Can you post some of your code? What data are you sending to your server from the front-end, and then how are you processing that data? What 'events' are you then trying to send back to the front end?

Comment: I gave a little more detail. I'm pretty new to node so it might be lacking still, please let me know if it is!

Comment: Most likely you would use websockets for something like this. i.e.

`form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
 socket.emit('progress', {received:bytesReceived, expected:bytesExpected});
});`

Comment: WebSockets, or server-sent-events perhaps. Are you deploying to the internet? How many users will you have? You could also use a long-timeout HTTP request which trickles progress back as it happens.

Comment: I don't know much about formidable, but if you need your server to push information down to the client (without the client explicitly requesting it constantly) websockets are your best bet. `socket.io` is a great websockets library for node.js.